# Is this a safe code?

Tags: c++, virtual, destructor

> My question is do you think that the code shown below is safe?  Can this code, as is, generate a    run-time failure like: `__PureVirtualCalled() at 0x9000000007ef90c?`
>
> By the way, I have compiled this code using g++ 4.3.2 on GNU Linux (64 bit). The output is:
>
> ```
> ~derived called.
> ~base() called.
> ~base() called.
> foo() called.
> ```
>
> Please note that the code given below is just a small program that I wrote to explain the problem. The real class is actually an implementation of a reference counter, that disposes itself only when its count is down to zero. The reason for invoking the destructor manually is to avoid the overhead of a virtual function call (the reference counter class is derived from an abstract counter class). It is possible to suppress virtual call by explicitly specifying the function one is intend to call especially if the class is the most derived one. However, that clearly does not work for virtual destructors.
>
> One more information, the real application which got the above mentioned error is a multi-threaded application.
>
> Please note that I am trying to get an explanation as to why the runtime is raising the above mentioned error. It is doing so intermittently.
>
> The code

```
#include <iostream>

class base {
public:
    virtual ~base() {
        std::cout << "~base() called." << std::endl;
    }

    virtual void dispose() = 0;

    void foo() {
        dispose();
        std::cout << "foo() called." << std::endl;
    }
};

class derived : public base {
public:
    ~derived() {
        std::cout << "~derived called." << std::endl;
    }

    void dispose() {
        // Intention here is to suppress the virtual function call. 
        this->derived::~derived();
        delete this;
    }
};

int main() {
    base* ptr = new derived;
    ptr->foo();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you even doing this (i.e. what are you trying to achieve)?

Comment: I don't see how it may generate PureVirtualCalled but tons of other problems for sure. what's the point to have a `dispose()` when you have a destructor? Why on earth you call `delete this`?

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti He is probably trying to implement some garbage collector garbage.

Comment: Obviously not. You are deleting twice (your code + compiler) a same object, which will lead to memory leak. As long as you have a virtual destructor of the base class, you don't need to specifically delete it.

Comment: You're trying to suppress a virtual function call by... implementing a virtual function?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your responses so far. I know that the code is not quite right. My question specifically is why in some cases the runtime raises the above mentioned error?

Comment: By the way, it is possible to suppress a virtual function call by invoking it in the way described above. However, I don't think the rule is applicable for destructors. The reason for doing above is optimisation. The idea is to avoid the cost of invoking a virtual function. This is obviously an example I made up, but the original class is a reference counter which is derived from an abstract counter class. The implementation deallocates the memory only when the counter is down to zero.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but...

The lines:

```
this->derived::~derived();
delete this;
```

result in undefined behavior.  First you explicitly destruct the
object, then you invoke `delete`, which calls the destructor on
what has effectively become raw memory.  The `delete this;`
should be enough.  The only time you want to explicitly call
destructors is when separating allocation and initialization,
and in that case, you'll have used placement new to construct
the object.